# Stop notification sound when pressing volume button

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

I use the attached code for setting an alarm. This works fine, except for one thing. If the phone is turned off and the notification starts, you can't stop it by pressing the volume button like you can by your alarm clock.

Does anyone know how this is handled or where I can find this?

Thank you very much!

```
public class OneShotAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "bla", System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, Personal.class), 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "bla", "blabla", contentIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notification.sound = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra("notificationTone");
    if (intent.getBooleanExtra("vibrationEnabled", true)){
        notification.vibrate = (long[]) intent.getExtras().get("vibrationPatern");
    }

    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

}
```

}